# Is it possible to access an object of an activity fom other place?

Tags: android, android-activity

This maybe a stupid idea, but does anyone know is it possible to access one activity's object form other places?

To be specific, lets say if you have an activity A (with a textView t) and you create a normal java class B.

At onCreate, you start to run B for some calculation like below,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputtext);
    Somejava B = new Somejava();
    B.run();
  }
}
```

Is there a way for B to update the textView?

I know the simple way (maybe the correct way) is to return the result from B class and use t.setText(result) in MyActivity, but I'm just want to know is it possible to update the textview in B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can simply pass activity refernce to b in constructor and create the method in your acitivty to update textview. if you using another thread not forgot to use handler or other ways to update UI thread.

Comment: sorry, i'm really new to android, can you please explane how you pass activity reference to b? I use B = new classB(this)... and then constructor of B is public B (Activity activity) {} ... it doesn't seems to work

Comment: why ? you can create be more specific here if not conformable with this...  1- can use public B (MyActivity activity) {}  2- create method updateTextView() in  MyActivity  3 - call activity.updateTextView() from classB ...........

Comment: sorry, I got some error message say Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views, I though I didn't pass the activity correctly, but I just figure out I didn't use a handler in my method... so, thank you that works !

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent or public static variables

Comment: I have see alot of example on internet about intent, but all the examples I've seem are use it to pass an object to a new activity, but in my case, B is just a noraml java class that runs some calculatio at background. Can you still use intent here?

Comment: I've try to use static variable, and it give error says: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFormWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Comment: when you close your Activity use `onActivityResult` in Activity A

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if the Activity's field is public and post the UI changes in a `public Handler` created on the first `Activity` but in facts, it's really ugly to do that...

---

You can use `startActivityForResult(...)` to notify an other activity how the process has passed with some serialiezable data in the `Bundle extras` of the Intent and catch the result in the `overrided` method `onActivityResult(...)`...

Comment: ok.. here's the thing.. I don't want to create an other activity.. The class B is just a normal java class (not an android activity)

Answer (score 0):

For a "normal java class" `B` I would work with `interfaces`

```
public interface SomejavaListener{
    void onSomejavaFinish(Object result);
}

public class MyActivity implements SomejaveFinish extends Activity {
  TextView t;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputtext);
    Somejava B = new Somejava();
    B.run(MyActivity.this); //notice the extra argument!
  }

  public void onSomejavaFinish(Object result){
    t.setText("updated! ^,^");
  }
}

public class Somejava {
    //...
    public void run(SomejavaListener callback){
        //working working
        callback.onSomejavaFinish( new Object() );
    }
}
```

However in respect to the android environment the question is sitting in I got the feeling maybe an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be the right thing for you. It has an `doInBackground` method to do work and not spoiling your UI Thread (resulting in ANR Errors.)
Another advantage is the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods are running in the UI Thread itself again, so it just takes a blink to update your `TextView`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t;

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... void) {
         //do your stuff
         return null
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
         MyActivity.this.t.setText("updated ^^v");
     }
 }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputtext);
    MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    myAsyncTask.execute();
  }
}
```